# Unable to correctly use many-to-many using belongsToMany

Tags: sequelize.js

I have been stuck trying to figure this one out for some time. I read that `hasMany` isn't the correct approach when trying to make a `many-to-many` association. I have two tables to create a following association `User` and `Follower` (terrible name for now).

**Follower**

```
const follower = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Follower = sequelize.define('follower', {
    follower_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
            notNull: true
        }
    },
    following_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
            notNull: true
        }
    }
  });

  return Follower;
};

module.exports = follower;
```

Next we have the **User Model** as

```
const user = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('user', {
      email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        unique: true,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
            isEmail: true,
            notEmpty: true
        }
      },
      password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
            notEmpty: true
        }
      },
      username: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        unique: true,
        allowNull: false
      }
  });

  User.associate = (models) => {
    User.hasMany(models.post, { foreignKey: 'user_id' });
    User.belongsToMany(models.user, { 
        through: 'users_followers', 
        foreignKey: 'follower_id',
        otherKey: 'following_id',
        as: 'followers', 
    });
    User.belongsToMany(models.user, { 
        through: 'users_followers', 
        foreignKey: 'following_id',
        otherKey: 'follower_id',
        as: 'following', 
    });

  return User;
};

module.exports = user;
```

Am I doing something wrong in regards to creating an association of many to many? I am asking since I keep trying difference variation but am unable to perform a query when trying to `include: [db.follower]`

Thank you for all the help

**Additional Info**

Query being run is:

```
const fetchUser = async (root, args, context) => {
  const { db, user } = await context();
  const { id } = args;
  
  const fetchedUser = await db.user.findOne({ 
      attributes: {
          include: [
            [sequelize.literal('(select count(*) from users_followers where users_followers.follower_id=users.id)'), 'followers_count'],
        ]
    },
    include: [
        'followers',
        'following'
    ],
    where: { 
        id 
    }, 
    raw: true 
});

return fetchedUser;
```

Comment: Show a query you re trying with many-to-many

Comment: @Anatoly Thanks for the reply. In the bottom of the question I've added the query where I am running the many-to-many

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `include` option you always should indicate a model that is on the other side of a defined association. In this case it's `User` model with two different aliases:

```js
include: [
{
  model: db.user,
  as: 'followers'
}, {
  model: db.user,
  as: 'following'
}],
```

Comment: Thank you for this info. Although I have two question. Currently, it is not returning any values (followers/following info is null) even though my subquery is returning accurately the amount of followers/followering of a user. Is there something else I need to include? I tried adding a where clause to the second one and got `"column following.follower_id does not exist"` Not sure why it's mentioning a following table when it should be users_followers through. Thank you again for the help and pointer.

Comment: You can check and compare a SQL generated by Sequelize with your own SQL